# If $A$ is a real diagonalizable matrix and $B$ is real symmetric and positive definite, is the matrix $B^{-1}A$ real diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

This problem is from a generalized eigenvalue problem. I can only proof it when $A$ is symmetric:

Let $G$ be the square root of $B$ and $G = G^T$, then $B^{-1}A = G^{-1}(G^{-1}AG^{-T})G$ is similar to $G^{-1}AG^{-T}$, which is again symmetric and thus diagonalizable.

However, this method fails when $A$ is just real diagonalizable. Are there any tricks to modify the proof, or is there a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not true. Take
\begin{align*}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & -1/2
\end{pmatrix}, \quad
B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1/2 \\
-1/2 & 1
\end{pmatrix} > 0,
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
B^{-1}A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
is not diagonalizable. But $A$ is clearly diagonalizable because it has two distinct eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for a counterexample, start with a matrix $C$ that is not diagonalizable,
and see if you can find a symmetric positive definite matrix $B$ so that $A = BC$ is
diagonalizable. Almost any one will do.